# Android AsyncTask Dialog fast close

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

My code:

```
private class selectBookInAutor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        arr_book_title.clear();
        arr_book_href.clear();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }       

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
            Elements links = doc.select("li>a");
            for (Element link : links) {
                sb.append(link.text());
                arr_book_title.add(link.text());
                arr_book_href.add(Jsoup.clean(link.attr("abs:href"), Whitelist.basic()));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();           
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
        if (result != ""){
            final CharSequence[] items = arr_book_title.toArray(new CharSequence[arr_book_title.size()]);

            final ArrayList seletedItems = new ArrayList();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            builder.setTitle("Select The Difficulty Level");
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                    }else if(seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)){
                        seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                    }
                }
            }).setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    for (Object s : seletedItems){
                        String[] separated = selGroupParam.split(";");
                        String _idautor = separated[0].toString();                          
                        long id_book = db.insertBOOK(_idautor, arr_book_href.get(Integer.valueOf(s.toString())).toString(), "", arr_book_title.get(Integer.valueOf(s.toString())).toString());
                        new **saveBookInAutor().execute(arr_book_href.get(Integer.valueOf(s.toString())).toString(), _idautor, String.valueOf(id_book));**
                    }
                    refreshList();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }).create().show();             
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}    


private class saveBookInAutor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String _idautor, _idbook;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(_context);
        mProgressDialog2.setMessage("Save to file");
        mProgressDialog2.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog2.show();
    }       

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        String _html = "";
        _idautor = params[1];
        _idbook = params[2];
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
            _html = doc.select("dd").outerHtml();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Jsoup.clean(_html, Whitelist.basic());           
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
        if (result != ""){
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Save file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String html = "<html lang='ru'><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/></head><body>"+result+"</body></html>";
            //String html = result;
            **savePageToFile(_idautor + "_" + String.valueOf(_idbook), html);**
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mProgressDialog2.dismiss();
    }
}      


public void refreshList() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    _context.startActivity(intent);     
}



public void savePageToFile(String filename, String html) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(_context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(html);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

When you select a page and clicking "Ok" ProgressDialog mProgressDialog2 opens and displays just a 1 second. Because of this, I do not see the download Page or not.

How to make mProgressDialog2 displayed all the while to save the page as a file?

Thank you!

**UPD**

What i want is :

1. Start mProgressDialog.
2. After downloading the page disappears and AlertDialog comes with the question what to choose.
3. After choosing, mProgressDialog2 should be displayed as long as it downloads and saves the file in the webpage.

However mProgressDialog2 disappears in 1 second, and process of saving the file goes on in silence.

Comment: Just use one instance of ProgressDialog

Comment: Tried it. Does not work.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: When You used one instance, what problem you faced?? Did ProgressDialog disappear and still processing is going on??

Comment: Did ProgressDialog disappear and still processing - Yes!

Comment: declare progress bar globally and start in first class and dismiss that in post execute method of second class.

Comment: Tried it. Does not work.

Comment: Please update your code to one instance of ProgressDialog

Comment: dude start your second class in post execute of first class,then only it works.

Comment: and u r doing alot of work in post execute n first class,i think its a very light wt. thread and having very less time to execute.just do that in background. and use operator to check value logically dude.sometthing like if(!result.equals(" ")){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onPostExecute method, you unconditionally call

```
mProgressDialog2.dismiss();
```

This is closing the dialog immediately after it is displayed.  That call should be moved to the handler code for each of the buttons. (i.e.the onClick method for the positive and negative buttons)

Comment: Tried this method. Does not work. Dalog quickly closed, and the file continues to be recorded.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried this method"?  Are you saying that you moved the "dialog2.dismiss()" calls to the onClick methods (and out of the onPostExecute() method).  You need to do that to prevent the dialog to close immediately.

Comment: and if by "the file continues to be recorded" do you mean that the code in the onClick method for the positive button has executed?  Have you verified this either in a debugger or via log statements?

Comment: Please use logical condition as @Gopal said :  if(!result.equals(""))

Comment: Put this line "mProgressDialog2.dismiss();" in if after this savePageToFile call and in else before Toast.

Comment: Did. But no effect. I'm sorry.

Comment: public void refreshList() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    _context.startActivity(intent);     
}

The problem was in the code. He just reloads the page. But how to update ExpandableListAdapter without rebooting?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(14014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 11-06 22:58:31.702: E/AndroidRuntime(14014): java.lang.StackOverflowError                E/AndroidRuntime(14014):  at com.example.pagereader.ExpandableListAdapter.notifyDataChange(ExpandableListAdapter.java:271)

Answer (score 0):

in onPostExecute(),  compare Strings like

```
     if(!result.equals(""))
```

and try once.

use equals() method for String comparisons.

Comment: "comapring Strings with operators is a bad way" it's not a bad way, it is not at all a way, you can't compare strings with '==' operator it matched refrances and not values.